# too much space between item of enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I am using the package enumerate and my problem is when I look into the pdf, there is too much space between the items.
This is my code:

```
\textbf{Analyse}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \underline{le module du gradient}: le module du gradient etc...
\item \underline{l'orientation du gradient}: nous avons des valeurs bleus etc...
\item \underline{descripteur SIFT}: On voit 4 grand pics  etc...
\end{enumerate}
```

And this is the image of the pdf: [image]

I don't understand why I have so much space.

Comment: You have to provide a minimal compilable example that reproduces the problem. What happens if you add text after the enumeration?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). As @pluton suggested it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably have a big image just after the last line and you're using `\begin{figure}[H]`. Don't do it. Say `nous obtenons l'image en la figure~\ref{xyz}.` (I'm not fluent in French, please fix the grammar) and use `\label{xyz}` after the caption for the figure, letting it float with `\begin{figure}[htp]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe latex tries to fill the page since the following image doesn't fit on the same page. Try \raggedbottom in the preamble and see what happens.

Comment: That solved the problem!!! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: This cures the symptom, not the disease.

Comment: @ user3314570: that's a little off-topic, but let draw your attention to the fact that compound colour adjectives, in french, are invariable.